# Capital asset pricing model (CAPM) applied to countries

Tags: asset-pricing, markets

I'm struggling on trying to find a beta for an equially wighted profolio for three countries `(A, B,C)`.

All the data I'm given are montlhy retunrs of each countrys market indexes and risk free rates for each one as well.

I know whow to apply `CAPM` to a given set of shares and use a national index (such as the S&P500) in order to calculate betas fo each share, however in this case I have multiple risk free rates an multiple return on indexes so I don't know how to use each piece of information when trying to apply the `CAPM`.

I'm not using covariance method, but an Excel regression on $x = rm-rf$ and $y = ri-rf$